# Cannot connect to Oracle database via TCPS

Tags: oracle, ssl, wallet, dbeaver

We have an Oracle server set up and are using TCP with SSL as connection. This setup was made with the assistant wizard and we used the default settings pretty much everywhere (which also means that no tnsnames.ora or listener.ora exist). `lsnrctl status` shows that the correct ports are listening.

We are trying to connect to this database via DBeaver and SQuirrel SQL but cannot get it to work. We have set the vmargs for the programs to contain the certificate of the server (e.g. `dbeaver.exe -vmargs -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/...keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS`), which works fine.

Connecting to the database with a concrete JDBC URL string (`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=IP)(PORT=5500))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)))`) does not work and times out after 60 seconds without a proper error (IO Error: Got minus one from a read call). We have tried pretty much everything and cannot get it to work.

The ports are correctly assigned, the database can successfully get accessed with the normal TCP protocol and port 1521.`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)))`

Are we missing steps? There don't seem to be any firewall issues. The certificates seem to be working fine as well, but we cannot connect with any of the programs (or sqlplus via command line).

Anyone know what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Does your listener listen on the TPCS protocol? You should see in the output of `lsnrctl status`

Comment: Yes it does:

`Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=...)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=...)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/home/oracle/app/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/admin/testdb/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "testdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "testdbXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...`

Comment: You are trying to connect on port 5500 but that port is only used for EMExpress. See the “Presentation=HTTP”, that means that you don’t have a SQL*Net protocol there. You need another port for SQL*Net over TCPS. Have a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc,-tlsv12,-jks-or-oracle-wallets

Comment: Make sense, yes! Thanks for the link as well. I got it working now with a new port 2484, however, without following the link instructions (they will prove useful for our java client though). Seemingly important to note: separate the oracle server and client, do not operate them on the same machine, that didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear! You might want to answer your question yourself with the steps that you took, so that future users who google across this can benefit from your expertise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it to work. There are various sites online that show you how it's done. I used this one:
https://database.edorex.ch/blog/database-connection-with-a-certificate/

Getting the wallets set up, certificates set up and the user set up in the database were the most important steps. Additionally, I had to separate the server and client machines. The server is now on a VM and it works that way, I couldn't get it to work having both on the same machine.

Comment: Broken Link. Please include the solution to your answer next time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check out the [SSL blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) or our [OTN page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc-eecloud-3089380.html) for step-by-step instructions? If you are using TLSv1.2 then the JDK version and JDBC driver versions are very important.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work already though, see my answer. I had already double-checked the correct JDBC and JDK versions :)